# Appium - How to read log from iOS device using java

Tags: java, ios, webdriver, appium

I am trying to automate iOS app testing using appium and java. I was able to read log files generated for simulators at /Users/xyz/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/158d9eddabcdefyt586a334136/system.log

Where can i find the log when I am running a test on real device? I see the only way to do so is on xcode for now.

Has anybody faced this issue and can guide me ?

Comment: Though in its Beta phase. `driver.manage().logs()` might help you.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful[works in Android for sure] :

```
List<LogEntry> logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").getAll();            
for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
     if (entry.getMessage().contains(event)) { //
          System.out.println("Found the logs looking for.");          
       }
}
```

Digging in further I could find this which might be of some help in the course :

```
package io.appium.java_client.service.local.flags;
public enum IOSServerFlag implements ServerArgument{
...
    /**
     * if set, the iOS system log will be written to the console<br/>
     * Default: false
     */
    SHOW_IOS_LOG("--show-ios-log"),
...
}
```

Its also here : http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#server-flags

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the logs then you can use libimobiledevice library or lemonjar. Libimobiledevice is quite better then lemonjar.